# HBase - hbase:metadata holds info about non existing RegionServer ID - "Master startup cannot progress, in holding-pattern until region onlined."

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I cannot start Hbase Master because I am getting this error:

```
[Thread-18] master.HMaster: hbase:meta,,1.1588230740 
    is NOT online; state={1588230740 state=OPEN, ts=1569328636085, server=regionserver17,16020,1566375930434}; 
    ServerCrashProcedures=true. 
    Master startup cannot progress, in holding-pattern until region onlined.
```

Hbase Master is active and green but actually it is not started properly since it generates those WARNings in logs and actually I cannot even do the list in Hbase shell because then I get error: ERROR: `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing`

hbase:meta is referencing some non existing ID 1566375930434 which does not exist in WALs nor in zookeeper-client /hbase-unsecure/rs list.

I tried with these commands:

```
$ sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -rm -r /apps/hbase/data/WALs/

$ zookeeper-client rmr /hbase-unsecure/rs
```

I also tried and this:

```
rm -f /var/lib/ambari-metrics-collector/hbase-tmp/zookeeper/zookeeper_0/version-2/*
```

and restarted the Hbase but still always having the same issue.
If anyone can give me additional advice what to try.
Thanks

Comment: One thing that can be attempted is to clean up the ZNODE on zookeeper (referencing this: https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.3.0/bk_ambari-upgrade-major/content/upgrade_troubleshooting.html) . You can bring down the cluster, attempt this on the zk (hbase zkCli should take you to ZK typically) and bring the cluster back up!

Comment: Hi Ramachandran. So you are saying that I should clean this (since my AMS is embedded) rm -f /var/lib/ambari-metrics-collector/hbase-tmp/zookeeper/zookeeper_0/version-2/*  I already tried this also. And it didn't help. Do you have some other suggestion maybe? Thanks

Comment: Hi Dejan , the document also points to cleaning up the ZNODE on zookeeper itself. The part of the solution. You have to launch zkCli then do rmr on the ZNode specified and see if that helps. This is for distributed HBASE set up .

Comment: Hi Ramanchandran. Can you please tell me exact step that maybe should be done? I launched zkCli and then I did zookeeper-client rmr /hbase-unsecure/rs

Comment: Can you please add if something additional should be removed?

Comment: My AMS is not distributed. I already checked and it is embedded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We resolved this issue.
Solution is to

- stop Hbase
- log to **zookeeper-client** as root
- execute command ***rmr /hbase-unsecure/meta-region-server***
- start Hbase

Answer (score 1):

This is what resolved the problem for me:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/hdinsight/hbase/hbase-troubleshoot-start-fails#resolution

> sudo -u hbase hdfs dfs -mkdir /hbase-wals/WALs/,16000,1622012792000

Make sure to get the right path and server name from the logs.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe config Zookeeper with OS path. This error could happens when you start and stop many time. I will get this case, so I config Zookeeper dir with hdfs path. This is my hbase-site.xml

`<property> <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name> <value>hdfs://master:9000/user/hdoop/zookeeper</value> </property>`

Goodluck for you.